Power Automate Desktop losing control over browser
I have a flow working with ServiceNow, handling certain kind of tickets. It parses contents, OCRs attachments, assigns, reassigns, responds, closes case, goes to another case. When going to another case, every once in a while (5 % of cases?), the flow errors out with "Failed to assume control of Microsoft Edge". There is no timeout trying to open the site or anything, the browser doesn't even attempt to navigate to the new link and stays there, either not receiving input, or not reacting to it. This happens at very different times, sometimes a few minutes/cases in, sometimes after way longer, sometimes not at all. It is not access to the system either. When I open the browser manually and go to the link, I am still authenticated and it works.
I introduced a troubleshooting to close the browser and reopen a fresh instance, going to the same link, which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. The browser always gets closed, but sometime the new instance just doesn't start.
Any idea what might be the issue?
